# Group data by year, month, week and day

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database with sales records, what I want to do is to generate a JSON which shows all the dates between the oldest date and the most recent, and then group that info by year, month, week and day, each day will show a number (representing the quantity sold that day), if there's no data matching that date, the number should be 0.

I'm actually using PHP to solve this problem. I've tried so many solutions, but none of them seems to work.

Here's a screenshot of my query getting executed on PHPMyAdmin: https://prnt.sc/pe4twq

The final JSON should be something like this:

```
[ 
   { 
      "year":"2019",
      "months":{ 
         "January":{ 
            "week 1":{ 
               "day 3":{ 
                  "total":"3400"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
]
```

EDIT: Here's some code that I've tried

```php
foreach ($rows as $row):
        $date = $row['date'];
        $dates[] = $date;

        $first = reset($dates);
        $first = strtotime($first);

        $last = end($dates);
        $last = strtotime($last);

        $year = date('Y', strtotime($date));

        $years[] = $year;
    endforeach;

    //86400 = 24 hours
    for($i = $first; $i <= $last; $i+=86400) {

        $dt = date('Y-m-d', $i);

        $y = date('Y', strtotime($dt));
        $m = date('n', strtotime($dt));
        $w = date('W', strtotime($dt));
        $d = date('D', strtotime($dt));

        $allYears[] = $y;

        if (in_array($dt, $dates)) {
            $result[] = ['year' => $y, 'month' => $meses[$m], 'week' => $w, 'day' => $dias[$d], 'total'=>$row["total"]];
        } else {
            $result[] = ['year' => $y, 'month' => $meses[$m], 'week' => $w, 'day' => $dias[$d], 'total'=>"0"];
        }


    }



    echo json_encode($result);
```

What I do here is I generate all the dates between the first and the last year on my database, and then I assign the total to each date, generating a JSON object for every date of every year: http://prntscr.com/pe4yjj

Comment: Post your code what you tried.

Comment: @daremachine Sorry, I edited my question.

Comment: Revise the question such that there are no longer any screenshots within it.